# How to define Ability.rb (CanCan) correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I trying to define my abilities as following:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.role == 'admin'
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role == 'member'
      can :manage, [User,Post] , :id => user.id
      cannot :index, User # list users page
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

And have included `load_and_authorize_resource` on top of my `PostsController`.

If I understand the definitions, guest users SHOULDN'T have access to the `create` action from `PostsController` but they do.

Any explanation for this behaviour?

**EDIT**

Solved!

Just realized that I have forgot to add an `before_filter :authenticate_user!` since I'm using Devise for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Just realized that I have forgot to add an `before_filter :authenticate_user!` since I'm using Devise for authentication.